# What is the name of the mod(s) used in this Civ4 video?

Tags: mods, civilization-4, mod-identification

I was watching this playthrough of *Civ4* the other day and I would really like to know the name of the mod or mods used to get all the fancy buttons and overlays. Really bugs me, since he says several times that he uses mods, but doesn't specify which ones.

Comment: Voting to reopen as per [Where do we stand on Mod Identification Questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16608/4797)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know which overlays you mean – if you're talking about the grid overlay and square value overlays, that's just built-in Civ4. Use the toggle buttons above the mini-map.

The really fancy stuff is from [BUG mod](http://civ4bug.sourceforge.net/), which I highly recommend.